# ionic android always show message "allow to access photos, media, and files on your device?"

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build, ngcordova

I'm using Cordova Camera Plugin, it take pictures well, but when I will chose one of them from library, always show a message "allow to access photos, media, and files on your device?" on android.

I tried with:

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
<preference name="permissions" value="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

On my local config.xml.

I'm compiling with phonegap build (it's a requirement for the project use that compilator)

I have this service:

```
.service('CameraService', function($rootScope, $cordovaCamera){
        this.returnGetPicture = function(esCamara){
            if (esCamara) {
                this.fuente = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
            } else {
                this.fuente = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
            }
            var options = {
                quality : 100,
                destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType : this.fuente,
                allowEdit : true,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                targetWidth: 800,
                targetHeight: 800,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: false
            };
            return $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options);


        }
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.camaraGaleria = function (esCamara) {
        $scope.promise = CameraService.returnGetPicture(esCamara);
        $scope.promise.then(function (imageData) {
            $scope.imgURI = imageData;
        });
    };
```

I thought it could be permissions or some, but I really don't know why is that error happening, it just happen when I try to open picture gallery, not taking a picture.

Thanks and cheers

Comment: If it's just permission the app is asking for just choose Yes. Can you not do this?

Comment: Yes, you can allow the permission, but if you touch again the button will ask again

Comment: Was this ever solved? My app is doing this and I don't require photos or access to anything.

Comment: If I remember well I volved that using a newer version of Ionic, that was a Problem of the first version of Ionic (don't believe in me that was a long time ago), but if the app is not very big try building a new one if not try to use microservices like pattern but on front end